# My FaceTime cannot be activated

Tags: ios, facetime

I got an iPad 2 running iOS 6.0.1. and I really have no idea why my FaceTime cannot be activated.

I always got an error while log in (username or password is incorrect)

But actually the Apple ID and password is correct and it can be used for downloading apps and iMessage.

Comment: What kind of Apple ID do you have? Is it an e-mail address or just a username?

Comment: Hmmm. When activating Facetime it will send a silent SMS. Do you have any restrictions for sending text messages to service numbers? Also your iTunes account points to the store of your country? I know, this questions have nothing todo with user name and password. That's because I think, this is just a standard error message and there might be any other reason behind the issue as well.

Comment: Hi, the problem solved, it is not my fault, but actually my password has been expired but Apple just give the response that "the username or password is incorrect"...Yesterday I restored my device and do the first time boot config, after tried to login with my Apple ID, then Apple refused my logon and told me "Your password has been expired..." then after I changed my password, all problem solved...

Comment: OK. I'm glad you found the solution. Happy video calling!

Comment: Please consider answering your own question. We feel the site works much better when there is an accepted answer with a check mark to indicate you found a solution.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it was because my Apple ID was a username. I had to change it to an email address, but it sounds like you have your solution already, and you didn't have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This error is only set to appear if your username or password is indeed incorrect, it doesn't fire by random. My advice would be to reset your password using iForgot.

Comment: Oh, just saw that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, so I called apple phone support, and told them about the problem, and it worked fine.  I was on my mac (10.8) and it said Your password was incorrect even though it was correct.

If you still are having the issue, try giving apple tech support a call

Comment: Answer doesn't apply. OP already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I just have the feeling because of the lack of an accepted answer to state the correct answer down here:

**Always** try changing your password **first**. If that does not help you can look for further causes, but it will fix the issue in most cases. The same counts for iCloud giving issues, just be sure you log out completely and you have to enter your Apple ID all over again. (I've got a similar issue when I changed my Apple ID email address to a new one. I had to log out completely on all devices to get it to work properly.)

- Just change your password as it might have been expired.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly it's because the certificate in your iPad for FaceTime has expired. You should be able to get it working again by simply updating your iPad.

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3367

This article used to specify which iOS version needs to be updated, now its simplified to just telling users to keep their device up-to-date.